# selenium script unable to run

Tags: java, selenium

```
WebDriver driver;
      String baseUrl = "http://example.com";
    @BeforeClass  

  public void beforeClass() {
      System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.marionette","local path to geckodriver-v0.10.0-win64");
      DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
      capabilities.setCapability("marionette", true);
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
  }

  @Test
  public void login() throws InterruptedException {
      driver.get(baseUrl); 
      Thread.sleep(3000); 
  }

  @AfterClass
  public void afterClass() {
  }
```

this code I am trying to run using TestNG tool but it's failing.

It runs perfectly when using it as Java Application but I want to run this script as a `TestNG` script

Comment: Can you share import code. Need to see what you are trying to import

Comment: To run with TestNG script you must have to install TestNG application. If you don't know how to install the application, please reply and I will help you.

Comment: import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterClass;           These are the import statements I have used, and using selenium beta 3.0 version